# Edit C# row and column design

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to design using C#, the header, rows, columns of my Excel sheet created by C# code, but nothing is being changed whatever I add from the sources I found.

Note that my data comes from a query mentioned at the beginning of my code.

```
if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    VRExcelSheet sheet = new VRExcelSheet();
    sheet.SheetName = kvp.Key;
    file.AddSheet(sheet);

    int p = 0;
    for (p = 0; p <= dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; p++)
    {
        VRExcelColumnConfig colname = new VRExcelColumnConfig()
        {
            ColumnIndex = p,
            ColumnWidth = 15
        };
        sheet.SetColumnConfig(colname);
    }

    VRExcelRowConfig headerRowConfig = new VRExcelRowConfig()
    {
        RowIndex = 0,
        BGColor = "#85ADCB",
        FontColor = "#FFFFFF", // White font color for better contrast
        Bold = true // Bold header text
    };
    sheet.SetRowConfig(headerRowConfig);

    int x = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        VRExcelCell cell = new VRExcelCell()
        {
            Value = col.ColumnName,
            RowIndex = 0,
            ColumnIndex = x
        };
        x++;
        sheet.AddCell(cell);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= dataTable.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            VRExcelCell cell = new VRExcelCell()
            {
                Value = dataTable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString(),
                RowIndex = i + 1,
                ColumnIndex = j
            };
            sheet.AddCell(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

Even the bold = true sentence didn't affect the row

Comment: How is SQL, and SSMS (an IDE-like client for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure Synapse, etc) related here? I see no SQL, nor anything about the application in your question. I'm also not sure what Server's have to with the question either. I've removed these tags; if they are important to the question then [edit] it to improve the question and explain why they are relevant (and retag them).

Comment: I think the issue didn't require mentioning the queries above, it's a syntax issue I guess and I need guidance if possible.

This is only a piece of my code obviously